# Twitter bootstrap horizontal middle align container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having problem **centering my container**.

```
<div class="row centered-form center-block">
    <div class="container col-md-10">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="projectTabs">
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab1</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#Tab2" data-toggle="tab">Tab2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The main row is centered with approximately 65% width, but the **container which contains navigation tabs sticks in this main row left**.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you want the nav to be horizontally middle aligned?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the `col-md-offset-1` class to move the container toward the center. Bootstrap uses a 12 column layout system so `col-md-10` makes your `container` 10 columns wide but it starts on the left. Use offset to push the element over to the right by the indicated amount, so `col-md-offset-1` moves it 1 column to the right.

```
<div class="row centered-form center-block">
    <div class="container col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works. Thank you @mikelt21 not only giving me the answer but also explaining me the logic.